# Count value in output with normal rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables named TEST and STEPS which are related by Test-Id column.

I am able to get all required columns by doing a join as below.

```
select t.id,t.name,s.step_no,s.step_data
from test t,steps s
where t.id = s.testid
```

What I require is that, apart fro the columns, I also need the total count of rows for each match.

**Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/794508/1**

**Current Output:**

```
ID  NAME  STEP_NO  STEP_DATA
--  ----  -------  ---------
1   TC1   1        Step 1
1   TC1   2        Step 2
1   TC1   3        Step 3
2   TC2   1        Step 1
```

**Required Output:**

```
ID  NAME  STEP_NO  STEP_DATA  COUNT
--  ----  -------  ---------  -----
1   TC1   1        Step 1     3
1   TC1   2        Step 2     3
1   TC1   3        Step 3     3
2   TC2   1        Step 1     1
```

Where count is the total number of rows from the STEPS table for each Id in TEST table.

Please let me know if you need any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.id,t.name,s.step_no,s.step_data,counts.count
from test t 
     join steps s ON t.id = s.testid
     join (select testid, count(*) as count 
           from steps 
           group by testid) counts ON t.id = counts.testid
```

Comment: Do we have any option using OLAP?

Answer (score 2):

You could just add `count(*) over ...` to your query:

```
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.name,
  s.step_no,
  s.step_data,
  [count] = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY s.testid)
FROM
  test t,
  steps s
WHERE
  t.id = s.testid
```

You can read more about the OVER clause here:

- [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Please consider also getting into the habit of

- [**always specifying the schema for your tables**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix), e.g.

  ```
    test  ->  dbo.test
  ```
- [**using the proper JOIN syntax**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins), i.e. instead of

  ```
    FROM
      a, b
    WHERE
      a.col = b.col
  ```

do

```
    FROM a
    INNER JOIN b
      ON a.col = b.col
```

- [**ending your statements with a semicolon**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons).

So, taking all those points into account, we could rewrite the above query like this:

```
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.name,
  s.step_no,
  s.step_data,
  [count] = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY s.testid)
FROM
  dbo.test AS t
INNER JOIN
  dbo.steps AS s
ON
  t.id = s.testid
;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and advice. I am still learning. :)

Answer (score 0):

IS this works ....

```
DECLARE @test TABLE  
    (
     id int identity primary key, 
     name varchar(20) 
    );

INSERT INTO @test VALUES('TC1'), ('TC2');

DECLARE  @steps TABLE  
    (
     id int identity primary key, 
     testid int,
     step_no int,
     step_data varchar(100)
    );

INSERT INTO @steps(testid,step_no,step_data) VALUES
(1,1,'Step 1'), (1,2,'Step 2'),(1,3,'Step 3'),(2,1,'Step 1');

select t.id,t.name,s.step_no,s.step_data,(select SUM(testid) from @steps  where testid = s.testid)
from @test t,@steps s
where t.id = s.testid
```